# React.js: Bind to Existing Elements

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, reactjs

In Backbone.js, you can specify a view's element by using the `el` property or by calling `view.setElement()`.

Is there an equivalent way of hooking up a React.js component to an existing DOM element?

Comment: Perhaps this will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160763/can-a-react-component-manipulate-an-existing-dom-node/34630247#34630247

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with Backbone, but to hook a React component into the DOM you use the `renderComponent` function. The first arg is the component, and the second is a DOM element:

```js
React.renderComponent(<SampleComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

---

**Updated per the context given in the comments:**

React hooks up to an element by replacing its contents, but not the element itself. You can call `renderComponent()` more than once on that element and it will run the same diff algorithm each time. This is handy if you want to pass in different props, pre-render on the server, or render a different component entirely. The same process is used to update the actual DOM each time, just like if you were to use `setState()` within the component itself.

Comment: Doesn't that place the SampleComponent as a child of #app?  I think the OP's looking to replace an existing element with the component.

Comment: @EdwardMSmith Ah, I wasn't acquainted with Backbone's behavior. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you - yes to clarify, I'm referring to elements loaded server-side like a select menu option that needs to know whether its default sort order is ascending or descending. So the element already exists when the page loads and I need to use Backbone/React to bind additional behavior/data to it without having to render it from scratch with a client-side template or React component. I can expand my question if it's more helpful.

Comment: @cantera React controls the rendering (it needs to in order to effectively diff against its virtual DOM), so we're going to need to re-render it anyway. Unless you are pre-rendering on the server with `renderComponentToString()`, in which case it will run the diff and not change anything. Do you have a jsfiddle or some other example with more scope? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: In [React version 0.12](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#new-terminology-amp-updated-apis) `React.renderComponent` has been changed to `React.render`